# How to find the strongest competitors or which are largely matched in a Bipartite network?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite

I have nodes and edges:
[image]

The edge lists are [(1, "A"), (1, "B"), (1, "C"), (1, "D"), (2, "A"), (2, "D")]

So the strongest competitors here will be 1&2 in the first part and A&D in second part since they are matched more.

Which algorithm should I apply for this case?

A basic illustration is:

```
 # Initialise graph
B = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes with the node attribute "bipartite"
top_nodes = [1, 2]
bottom_nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
B.add_nodes_from(top_nodes, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(bottom_nodes, bipartite=1)
# Add edges only between nodes of opposite node sets
B.add_edges_from([(1, "A"), (1, "B"), (1, "C"), (1, "D"), (2, "A"), (2, "D")])
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the maximum matching of the bipartite graph here?

Comment: yes maximum matching, but i need the top two largest matches

Comment: What do you mean by top two largest matches?

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options in your hand:

- nx.bipartite.eppstein_matching(G[, top_nodes])
- nx.bipartite.hopcroft_karp_matching(G[, top_nodes])
- nx.bipartite.maximum_matching(G[, top_nodes])

Consider further reading from the [official documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html#module-networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matching). You can start with the following code to check and compare:

```
import networkx as nx

# Initialise graph
B = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes with the node attribute "bipartite"
top_nodes = [1, 2]
bottom_nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
B.add_nodes_from(top_nodes, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(bottom_nodes, bipartite=1)
# Add edges only between nodes of opposite node sets
B.add_edges_from([(1, "A"), (1, "B"), (1, "C"), (1, "D"), (2, "A"), (2, "D")])

print(nx.bipartite.eppstein_matching(B))
print(nx.bipartite.hopcroft_karp_matching(B))
print(nx.bipartite.maximum_matching(B))
```

Sample output:

```
{'A': 1, 'D': 2, 1: 'A', 2: 'D'}
{1: 'A', 2: 'D', 'A': 1, 'D': 2}
{1: 'A', 2: 'D', 'A': 1, 'D': 2}
```